# How to convert Char into Strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the `split(' ')` method in JavaScript to spilt the word for whitespaces.
For example:

I have text like:

```
var str ="Hello this is testing"
```

After I call

```
str.split(' ')
```

Now I will get **Hello this is tesing** as output and when I do this

```
str[2]
```

I get "l", but I want to get "**testing**" word (as per array index). How to convert str to array, so that if I put

```
str[2] //It should be testing.
```

Comment: aravinth str[2] should be the word "is" by what you are hoping to achieve

Answer (score 7):

When you do split it actually returns a value.

```
var foo = str.split(' ');
foo[2] == 'is' // true
foo[3] == 'testing' // true
str[2] == 'l' // because this is the old str which never got changed.
```

Comment: Except that `foo[2]` actually equals "is".

Comment: also `str[2]` would actually equal 'l'

Comment: you are welcome. don't forget to select a correct answer please.

Answer (score 6):

```
var a = str.split(" ");  // split() returns an array, it does not modify str
a[2];  //  returns "is";
a[3];  //  returns "testing";
```

Answer (score 3):

[`.split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) is returning your array, it doesn't change the value of your existing variable

example...

```
var str = "Hello this is testing";

var str_array = str.split(' ');

document.write(str_array[3]); //will give you your expected result.
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are not mutable, [`split`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) **returns** an array. You have to assign the return value to a variable. E.g.:

```
> var str ="Hello this is testing";
  undefined
> str = str.split(' ');
  ["Hello", "this", "is", "testing"]
> str[3]
  "testing"
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing `str.split(" ")` does not modify `str`.
Rather, it returns a new array containing the words.

You can write

```
var words = str.split(" ");
var aWord = words[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this html page and it reports the following:

```
function getStrs()
{
   var str = "Hello this is testing";
   var array = str.split(' ');
   for(var i=0; i < 4; i ++)
      alert(array[i]);
}
```

It reported Hello ... this ... is ... testing